# removing sub caption numbers

Tags: subfloats

I'm new to Latex and trying to make a figure with 3 subfigures. After drawing the subfigures, I hope to remove the numbers (a), (b) from their captions. Even I tried and searched google for more than 3 hours, I could't solve this problem. Could anyone please help me remove the numbers..?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\begin{figure}[h]
\subfigure[s-channel]{
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1[particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [anti fermion] i2[particle=\    (e^{-}\)],
  a -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] b,
  f1[particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [anti fermion] b -- [fermion] f2[particle=\    (e^{-}\)],
};}
\subfigure[t-channel]{
\feynmandiagram [vertical=a to b] {
  i1[particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [anti fermion] a -- [anti fermion]      i2[particle=\(e^{-}\)],
  a -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] b,
  f1[particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [anti fermion] b -- [anti fermion]      f2[particle=\(e^{-}\)],
};
}
\subfigure[u-channel]{
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{feynman}
\diagram [vertical'=a to b] { 
i1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)]
     -- [fermion] a
     -- [draw=none] f1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)], a -- [photon, edge label'=\(\gamma\)] b,
i2 [particle=\(e^{-}\)]
     -- [anti fermion] b
     -- [draw=none] f2 [particle=\(e^{-}\)], };
\diagram* {
   (a) -- [fermion] (f2), 
   (b) -- [anti fermion] (f1),

}; 
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}}


\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm using ShareLatex with tike-feynman template. I don't have subfig.sty and subcaption.sty in my project directory.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do note that the `subfigure` package is considered deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Instead, use either the [subfig package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/) or the [subcaption package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subcaption/).

Comment: than don'tt use `subfigure` (deprecated) or `subfloat` or `subcaption`. try to place images in `table` or `minipages`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `subfigure` package is considered deprecated. Use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package instead.

If, for some reason, you don't have access to either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package -- any modern TeX distribution should provide them, really -- you could employ three side-by-side `minipage` environments, as follows, to achieve your objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth} 
\centering
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1[particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [anti fermion] 
  i2[particle=\(e^{-}\)],
  a -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] b,
  f1[particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [anti fermion] b -- [fermion] f2[particle=\(e^{-}\)],
};
s-channel
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
\feynmandiagram [vertical=a to b] {
  i1[particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [anti fermion] a -- [anti fermion]      i2[particle=\(e^{-}\)],
  a -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] b,
  f1[particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [anti fermion] b -- [anti fermion]      f2[particle=\(e^{-}\)],
};
t-channel
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{feynman}
\diagram [vertical'=a to b] { 
i1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)]
     -- [fermion] a
     -- [draw=none] f1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)], a
     -- [photon, edge label'=\(\gamma\)] b,
i2 [particle=\(e^{-}\)]
     -- [anti fermion] b
     -- [draw=none] f2 [particle=\(e^{-}\)], };
\diagram* {
   (a) -- [fermion] (f2), 
   (b) -- [anti fermion] (f1),

}; 
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
u-channel
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```